# Protocol for exchanging b/w ROS and Linux devs

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please, advise the protocol for exchanging of information between the ROS and auxiliary functional elements based on Linux? Earlier was thinking to use [simple_massage](http://wiki.ros.org/simple_message)...

The problem is as follows:

- Have a central brain through ROS;
- Have several executive functional
  units made on Linux devices.

Necessary to provide communication between the functional units and the center.

With best regards,
Wagan Sarukhanov

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211454/protocol-for-exchanging-b/w-ros-and-linux-devs/) by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-06-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-06-16**:
What do you mean exactly with "auxiliary functional elements based on Linux"? Small embedded computers? Microcontrollers? Smart sensors?

**Comment by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) on 2015-06-16**:
You are right, it may be embedded controller or micro-PC or other. For example BeagleBone Black or CyberWRT device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps you can use [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial).

A more complete overview of some of the existing ROS client libraries targeted for use on embedded / small platforms is given in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/201885/cross-compile-ros_comm-for-arm9-lpc3250/?answer=201915#post-id-201915) answer to the [cross-compile ros_comm for ARM9 LPC3250](http://answers.ros.org/question/201885/cross-compile-ros_comm-for-arm9-lpc3250) question.

---

Edit:

> You are right, it may be embedded controller or micro-PC or other. For example BeagleBone Black or CyberWRT device

For Beagle Bone (Black) you could also run a full OS + ROS. See [wiki/BeagleBone](http://wiki.ros.org/BeagleBone) for more information. Whether that is appropriate depends on your specific use case / requirements.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) on 2015-06-16**:
Thank you very much

**Comment by [Wagan Sarukhanov](https://answers.ros.org/users/22367/wagan-sarukhanov/) on 2015-06-16**:\

> For Beagle Bone (Black) you could also run a full OS + ROS.

Yes it's may be very interesting but in some cases we can not install ROS on embedded devise, therefore I asked about the appropriate interaction protocols. Thank you again